# How to find and compare elements of character array

Tags: c++, c

I need to compare the elements of a string. I have tried to run the following code but this not work. Any idea how to access element of the string and compare against alphabets ?

```
char* my_string = "Excellent";

if ( strcmp (my_string[0], "D") ) 
{
 printf("\n\rThe First Element is D: \n\r");    
}

if ( strcmp (my_string[0], "E") ) 
{
 printf("\n\rThe First Element is E: \n\r");    
}
```

Comment: For comparing a single character, just use something like `if (my_string[0] == 'D')`.

Comment: my_string[0] == 'D'
my_string[0] == 'E'

or
switch(my_string[0]) {
case 'D':
...
case 'E':
...
}

Comment: By the way, `strcmp` returns 0 when the strings compare equal, so `if (strcmp(my_string, "Excellent")) { printf("The string is Excellent\n"); }` would not print anything. It would need to be something like `if (strcmp(my_string, "Excellent") == 0) { printf("The string is Excellent\n"); }` or `if (!strcmp(my_string, "Excellent")) { printf("The string is Excellent\n"); }`.

Comment: C or C++? They're different languages. If it's C++ why do you use `char*` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: Yes, this works. "if (my_string[0] == 'D')". I also need to copy only first four elements of the string. Here is my code but I don't get anything in the crop_string, it should have first four elements but it is empty when I print. 

   `char* my_string = "CoolText";
    char* crop_string = " ";
    strncpy(crop_string, &my_string[0], 4);
    crop_string[5] = '\0';`

Comment: `char* crop_string = " ";` doesn't create space to copy text into - it creates a pointer to a string literal with one space and a NUL, and that's in read-only memory so you can't make it a destination for `strncpy`.  If you want to create space to copy into, use an array of char: `char crop_string[5]; strncpy(crop_string, my_string, 4); crop_string[4] = '\0';`.  Better yet, if you can use C++ use `std::string` - it's much harder to make mistakes / crash your program.  See docs and examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: You can also simply dereference the string to obtain the first char, e.g. `if (*my_string == 'D') ...`  `my_string[0]` is equivalent to `*(my_string + 0)` which of course is simply `*my_string`...

Answer (score 3):

`my_string[0]` is a `char` and should be compared to `'D'` (another char) with `==`, not compared to "D" (a string literal) with `strcmp`, which is only suitable for [ASCIIZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ASCIIZ&redirect=no) (nul-terminated) strings.

Separately, you should (and in C++ at least *must*) use `const char* my_string = "Excellent";`, indicating that you can't change the text `my_string` points to (most compilers will put it in read-only memory, and even if they don't you shouldn't change it as the compiler's entitled to assume it won't ever be changed.).

Comment: I'd omit the part about const -- it's true, but keep it simple. Good answer.

Comment: @TopologicalSort: I've rolled back your edit - ASCIIZ was not a typo... it's a text storage convention consisting of ASCII characters and a ASCII "nul" (the proper three-letter code for an ASCII null-terminator).  (Sometimes best to ask before assuming people have made mistakes and editing their answers.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is comparing the char(my_string[0]) to the string("D") which is unacceptable by `strcmp(char *arg1, char *arg2)`. You can compare the characters by using '==', '>' and '<' operators like

```
if( my_string[0] == 'E' )
  printf("\n\rThe First Element is E: \n\r");
```